# How to set properties on other fields oninput with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have three inputs, and I'm trying to make it so that a user can enter any number of them, but at least one, in order to do a search. The backend is built to handle it just fine parsing these from the URL, but I'm having trouble client-side.

Right now, I'm using `oninvalid` and `oninput` like so:

```
<input type="text" id="Input1" name="Input1" required oninvalid=
"setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
```

What I'm trying to do is, in this package of 3 inputs, set the other two inputs to not be `required`and have a `setCustomValidity` value of `''` when a value is entered in one of the fields. I also would like it to re-establish those rules if, say, the user were to change their mind after typing into the wrong field.

The JQuery I have right now:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
            var $inputs = $("#Input1, #Input2, #Input3")
            $inputs.oninput = (function () {
                // Set the required property of the other input to false if this input is not empty.
                $inputs.not(this).prop('required', false)
                $inputs.not(this).prop("setCustomValidity", "")
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="get">

<input type="text" id="Input1" name="Input1" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, 2, or 3')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>

<input type="text" id="Input2" name="Input2" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, 2, or 3')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>

<input type="text" id="Input3" name="Input3" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1, 2, or 3')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Everything seems to compile correctly in Razor Pages etc with no errors, but the required properties are not being removed or changed. If anyone could offer insight into what I'm doing wrong, it'd be splendid; I'm new to JS and JQuery in general, but I can see it's powerful stuff.

Comment: can you check if there's a valid input and go with that? 

if (!$("#input1").val() && !$("#input2").val() &&  !$("#input3").val() ) {
 //show warning
} else {
 //get valid input and do your thing
}

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no key/value pair for the `required` attribute. It's either required or not. So change your `prop('required', false)` to `removeAttr('required')`. I'd also make sure that those inputs are actually changing. Check the inspector to see if they did indeed change.

Comment: @MPaul Unfortunately, they are changing at all with the current code, but I will try changing the required attribute code and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I did change it, but the inputs do not seem to be changing, and I am not triggering any sort of error or console output from the chrome debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCustomValidity` isn't a property or attribute, it's a function that you call from the `oninvalid` attribute. So it should be:

```
$inputs.not(this).removeAttr("oninvalid");
```

And when you want to re-establish it, use:

```
$inputs.not(this).attr("oninvalid", "setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid Input1')");
```

But I'm not sure you need to do this. Once you make it not required, it should never trigger the "invalid" event. So you don't need to remove it at all.

You can also do this with jQuery event listeners. To add the handler:

```
$elements.on("invalid", function() {
    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid input");
}
```

To remove it:

```
$elements.off("invalid");
```

You also have a typo in the assignment of `$this`. It should be:

```
var $inputs = $("#Input1, #Input2, #Input3");
```

And there is no jQuery `.oninput()` method. So it should be:

```
$inputs.on("input", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi there Barmar, I actually edited the question shortly after your answer, my apologies. I added `I also would like it to re-establish those rules if, say, the user were to change their mind after typing into the wrong field.` This implementation would remove it for good, no? +1 for your observation of the attribute, however.

Comment: Use `.attr("oninvalid", "setCustomValidity('Whatever')")` to add it back.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm still currently having trouble removing the required property, however; the properties don't seem to be changing with either .prop or .removeAttr, nor is there console output.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's not working. I have applications of my own that change the `required` property dynamically, and it works fine.

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you, but judging from the snippet above as well it doesn't seem to be functioning as intended; I assume I've made some sort of syntax error that isn't showing up.

Comment: `var $inputs = ("#Input1, #Input2, #Input3")` is missing the call to the `$()` function, it should be: `var $inputs = $("#Input1, #Input2, #Input3")`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that. It still seems to be having the same issue; I've remedied it in the snippet above as well.

Comment: There's no `.oninput()` method in jQuery. Aren't you getting console errors from all these mistakes?

Comment: My apologies, I was not aware of this! No, I haven't actually gotten any console errors from there for whatever reason, and I have in my previous experimentation. I'll have to find a different way, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, @Barmar.